# Duplicate logs from databricks notebook with custom log4j appender

Tags: scala, log4j, databricks, appender

I have created a custom log4j appender for use in databricks to log job errors to slack:

```
package aaa.bbb.slackAppender

import org.apache.http.client.methods.{CloseableHttpResponse, HttpPost}
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import org.apache.log4j.{AppenderSkeleton, Level}
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent
import org.json.simple.JSONValue

class SlackAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
  override def append(event: LoggingEvent): Unit = {

    val level = event.getLevel

    if (level == Level.ERROR) {

      val escaped = JSONValue.escape(event.getMessage.toString)

      val escapedMessage = "{\"text\":\"" + escaped + "\"}"

      val post = new HttpPost("https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXX/YYYY/ZZZZ")
      post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
      post.setEntity(new StringEntity(escapedMessage))

      val client = HttpClientBuilder.create.build
      val response:CloseableHttpResponse = client.execute(post)
      val entity = response.getEntity
      val str = EntityUtils.toString(entity,"UTF-8")
      println("Error post response code is " + str)

    }
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {}

  override def requiresLayout(): Boolean = true
}
```

It is basically working when run from a notebook or job like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{LogManager, Level, Logger}
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
import aaa.bbb.slackAppender.SlackAppender

Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new SlackAppender());

val log = LogFactory.getLog("misc-test-log")
log.error("errorA")
log.error("errorB")
log.error("errorC")
```

However, when run from a notebook, it is duplicating the logs N times if I have run the notebook N times.  In other words, after the first run I am seeing in Slack:

```
errorA
errorB
errorC
```

After 5 runs, I am seeing something like:

```
errorA
errorA
errorA
errorA
errorA
errorB
errorB
errorB
errorB
errorB
errorC
errorC
errorC
errorC
errorC
```

It seems like the logs are being saved somehow and re-logged each time.  Thankfully, I don't see the same thing when I run the notebook as a Job.

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how I can make it stop?

Comment: Do you know if any other side effects are repeating?  Notebooks in general are notorious for weird execution semantics which only directly show up in the presence of side effects.

Comment: @LeviRamsey I am not aware of any other side effects, but I did find out that each call to rootLogger.addAppender(new SlackAppender) was adding another appender!  I am not sure if this is a side effect or normal notebook behavior.

Comment: While I can't say I'm too familiar with notebooks (or log4j, for that matter), that does sound like the sort of weird execution semantics I've heard about in notebooks.  There are a couple of possibilities: If you can get which appenders you've already added to the `rootLogger`, you can prevent the appender from being added a second time.  Alternatively, if you make `SlackAppender` an `object` (i.e. a singleton), you can have it dedupe logs (keep a buffer of the last few `events` and not log to slack if it's a duplicate).

Comment: Of course, if the notebook is executing code across multiple JVMs, neither of those approaches will work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Levi Ramsey's comment above, changing:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new SlackAppender());
```

to:

```
new SlackAppender().initializeAppender()
```

where initializeAppender() is:

```
  def initializeAppender() {
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger

    val en: util.Enumeration[_] = rootLogger.getAllAppenders()
    while ( {en.hasMoreElements}) {
      val appender: Any = en.nextElement
      if (appender.isInstanceOf[SlackAppender]) {
        val slackAppender: Appender = appender.asInstanceOf[Appender]
        rootLogger.removeAppender(slackAppender)
      }
    }
    rootLogger.addAppender(new SlackAppender)

  }
```

Still testing but this seems like a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with Python notebooks. Resolved it in the same way as in the @chrismead answer - added names for my RootLogger handlers and check if handlers are already added to the logger.

```
handlers_names = []
for h in logger.handlers:
    handlers_names.append(h.name)

if <handler name 1> not in handlers_names:
    <add handler 1>

if <handler name 2> not in handlers_names:
    <add handler 2>
```